# Differences between requiring local module versus node_modules module

Tags: node.js, graphql

A have the following transpiled code in a private library, which is inside `node_modules` folder.

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _graphql = require('graphql');

var FileTypeEnum = new _graphql.GraphQLEnumType({
  name: 'FileType',
  description: 'The types of report files.',
  values: {
    CSV: {
      value: 'CSV',
      description: 'Comma-separated values.'
    },
    XLS: {
      value: 'XLS',
      description: 'Microsoft Excel.'
    }
  }
});

exports.default = FileTypeEnum;
```

My problem is when I require it, it comes a object with the correct properties but not an instance of GraphQLEnumType. On the other hand, if a make a copy of this module inside my project, like a local module, it works perfectly.

```
import FileTypeA from 'my_lib/graphql/report/types/FileTypeEnum';
import FileTypeB from '../types/FileTypeEnum';

console.log(FileTypeA instanceof GraphQLEnumType); # false
console.log(FileTypeB instanceof GraphQLEnumType); # true
```

I can't use this class without being a GraphQLEnumType. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be that your "private library" in `node_modules` depends on a different version of `graphql` than your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your library has a different graphql version than your application.